# Python Plotting. How to plot f(x,y)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, correlation

I am rather new to Python. I have one column of data x and another columns of data y (They're both float). I've saved them both as lists a and b.

I wanted to plot the correlation and also the standard deviation between 10 rows of a and b. So in essence, I want to plot:

```
   |
   |
 x |  corr(x,y), stdev(x,y)
   |
   |
   |_________
        y
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this in Python?

Comment: Are you saying that you are looking to plot two scalars, i.e. one 2D point?

Comment: As I said, I'm really new to it... I just simply tried:

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.axis([a[0],a[len[a]-1],b[0],b[len[b]-1])

Comment: Yeah, I need to plot a function from the two scalars, the correlation while keeping the two scalars on the axis..

Comment: ok... i just noticed that we can do it with a scatter plot. Is there any way I can do this with a line graph though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question ... plotting 2 lists in function of each other (correlation) I would like to refer to [following website](http://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-2-lines-points-formatting/), which has a very clear example.

Could you please elaborate (clarify) the second part of your question (stdev.)?

Would you like to plot the standard deviation on the dataset (being 1 constant?)?
Or do you want to plot the standard deviation in function of the correlation (don't know a lot about statistics but i'm nut sure if that's meaningful :D ) ?

regards,

M.